# PyUSB with windows, libusb1 and libusb-win32 backends not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm trying to read from a USB device. To do this, I'm using PyUSB which is raising multiple issues.

### Error

With libusb-win32, no devices are found. After finding out that it had limited support I switched to libusb1

With libusb1, some devices are found, however an error is raised `NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform`

### Setup

I'm using Windows10, and the device is an M10 10lb Digital Postal Scale

I'm installing the device driver using Zadib with the following settings
[image]

When the device is connected, I can see it in the device manager.

I've downloaded the sources for [libusb-win32](https://sourceforge.net/p/libusb-win32/wiki/Home/) and [libusb1](https://libusb.info/) and added them to the %PATH% environment variable (but only one a time is in %PATH% so I know which is in use).

- Without the PATH pointing to one of the `.dll` files, PyUSB raises an error that no backend is found

### Code

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# find the USB device
for device in usb.core.find(find_all=True):
    print(device)
```

### Complete Error Message

Note that two devices are successfully printed before this error messages comes up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 727, in __str__
    for configuration in self:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 1094, in __iter__
    yield Configuration(self, i)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 586, in __init__
    configuration
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 757, in get_configuration_descriptor
    config, byref(cfg)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 595, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 2] Entity not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reading_dymo_scale.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(device)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 731, in __str__
    configuration = self.get_active_configuration()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 875, in get_active_configuration
    return self._ctx.get_active_configuration(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 236, in get_active_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 120, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 786, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 643, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 593, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform
```

Answer (score 2):

After a few hours of trial and error last night, I found my solution. Of course it seems obvious now

- the zadib driver should match the backend driver should both be libusb-win32, so far no luck with other drivers/backends

## Solution

1. download [libusb-win32 sources](https://sourceforge.net/p/libusb-win32/wiki/Home/)
2. add the `libusb-win32/bin/amd64/` folder to the %PATH% environment variable so PyUSB can find it
3. install PyUSB `pip install pyusb`
4. download zadig if you need to install a driver for your USB device
5. open zadig and add your usb device using the libusb-win32 driver. Example [image]
6. You should now be able to run your code, try testing it with

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

# find the USB device
for device in usb.core.find(find_all=True):
    print(device)
```

### Debugging

- if the terminal was open before you set the PATH, then a new terminal needs to be opened
- if driver still can't be found, try restarting. Also check device manager to see if the device can be found that way